# Android studio calendar set maxDate 18 years ago

Tags: android

my android application needs a calendar that has a maxDate that is 18 years ago from now. So far I tried this code but it only says `Integer number is too large`

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    view.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 31556926000);
    year_x = year;
    month_x = monthOfYear + 1;
    day_x = dayOfMonth;
    etBirthDate.setText(month_x + "/" +  day_x + "/" + year_x);
}
};
```

Answer (score 8):

To better understand your problem see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html section **Integer Literals**. 
It states that:

> An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l; otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish from the digit 1.

Simplest solution:

```
view.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 31556926000L);
```

But I would go with:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
view.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 final Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(
            getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker,
                              int selectedyear, int selectedmonth,
                              int selectedday) {
            selectedyear=selectedyear;
            mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedyear);
            mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedmonth);
            mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedday);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
            edtxtDOB.setText(sdf.format(mcurrentDate.getTime()));


        }
    }, mYear-18, mMonth, mDay);
    mcurrentDate.set(mYear-18,mMonth,mDay);
    long value=mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis();
    mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(value);
    mDatePicker.show();
```